How to properly set up WebStorm for debugging of Create-React-App projects?
I am working on a React project in WebStorm (created with 'npx create-react-app'). I would like to be able to step through my code within WebStorm (I like working with IDEs... I would be curious about some data points on how other front-end developers debug their code, do you exclusively use the browser's debugger?).
So far, I was unable to configure WebStorm in a way so that this works reliably. I followed both described paths from their official support website: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/react.html#react_running_and_debugging_debug. However, these solutions do not work consistently:
Official Approach #1: Run and debug a React application with a single npm run/debug configuration

This mostly works for the first few break points, but after a few modifications in the code, the breakpoints will not be picked up anymore. Then, only a restart of the debugging session might help, subject to the issues below.
Even if a browser is correctly configured on the Browser / Live Edit tab (Chrome, in my case), WebStorm sometimes does not open any browser, sometimes it opens FireFox, sometimes Chrome, sometimes both of them, and most of the time two tabs within the same browser, only one of them being the "correct one", spamming my desktop with browser windows and tabs over time.
Once the breakpoints are "broken" (i.e. not picked up anymore), restarting the debugger in WebStorm will often not help to make it pick up the breakpoints again until all instances of Chrome are completely shut down and restarted. Even then, this is not guaranteed.
As a nit, the Before Launch options at the bottom of a Run/Debug configuration does not seem to do anything reliable either. Sometimes, but rarely, it works, most of the time, it doesn't. For instance, adding a "Launch Web Browser" option there is simply ignored.

Official Approach #2: Start debugging with a JavaScript Debug run/debug configuration

Exactly the same problems as above.


Does anybody use WebStorm for debugging in a professional capacity? If so, could you please share how you set it up so that it works reliably? Thanks so much in advance.
